ETA's are wrong every time, how to fix it?
when I copy-paste data from my laptop (Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS) to an external hard drive on nautilus, for instance, I get a few info while the process is running, namely

nof file processed/nof files to process;
time left (ETA);
and speed (e.g. 100 MB/sec).

However, when this data is a lot, for instance for a backup, the ETA is blatantly wrong every time, with the noticeable exception of the very last few seconds or maybe even minutes of the process.
This is due to the fact that, for reasons unbeknownst to me, the speed changes over time, in particular it decreases rapidly at first (~550 MB/sec to 36.5 MB/sec in a few minutes) just to slow down in its descent later and then it kind of stabilizes (apparently, but I'm not sure). This messes with the calculation of the ETA, since instead of decreasing, it increases at first, and I'm pretty sure that time is not running backwards in my location, also five minutes ago I wasn't even doing the backup, so history is been re-written.
To test this, I let a pen fall on the ground and it went in the right direction.
In turns, this comes from the fact that (clearly) the ETA is estimated in the simplest way possible: amount of data left divided by the instantaneous speed.
This, of course, doesn't work if speed is a function of time, as it clearly is the case for data transfer and falling pens.
My questions are: where in the filesystem can I find the part that estimates the ETA for nautilus? Is there a way to integrate it with, let's say, python code that computes the ETA more accurately (I'm not asking you how to write this code, just about the integration)? What about midnight-commander? It's affected by the same problem.
Thank you very much in advance
Edit: this happens to some capacity regardless of which type of external hard drive I'm using, the laptop I'm using, the Ubuntu version I'm using, the other processes happening in the mean time. It looks like this abrupt speed decrease is something intrinsic in laptop-external drive data transfer.

The rate of transfer will also be affected by any other tasks you're doing on the computer, especially read/writes to the two drives (the source and destination).  Perhaps you can make nautilus a higher priority job?  Maybe that might make the ETA more accurate?

Hello, thank you for your comment, I'm not sure that, in my case, this would be a solution because: (1) this happens regardless of whatever else is going on and (2), nautilus is not the most important thing that is usually going on in my pc, regarding my work, so at least for me it's not worth it, even if it would make things better in terms of ETA calculations =) This is why I was thinking of computing it on my own, it looks like it's something intrinsic in how data transfer works, rather than circumstantial. Thank you again!

The problem is that files are read into memory first, at a huge rate of speed, filling an internal buffer and giving the impression that the transfer is happening very quickly; that quickly hits a wall once this buffer is filled up and the actual write to the disk starts bottlenecking the whole process. Unless I'm mistaken, without delving into hacking the ETA, there are tweaks you can do at kernel level to mitigate this issue.

I agree with kos, the problem is probably due to filling a buffer in RAM, and then slowly flushing the buffer. You can monitor that process, for example according to this link.

Don't quote me on this, but this could be what you want: https://superuser.com/a/160186/427197 .  You can test this by plugging the device in, unmounting it and mounting it manually using e.g. sudo mount -o sync /dev/whatever1 /mountpoint (this is necessary as auto-mount is handled differently); on how to make this automatic, that's another matter, maybe first try it out like this.

@kos I believe you are correct  "where in the filesystem can I find the part that estimates the ETA for nautilus? " ... core_utils probably

Another simpler alternative to the script @sudodus linked: watch -d grep -e Dirty: -e Writeback: /proc/meminfo

Also (finally), a dirty workaround I sometimes use is copying files with pv with the -L option set to a maximum transfer rate slightly above the expected performance of the target disk, this effectively prevents building up buffers (obviously this works just for a single file). There may be option in rsync and other utilities to do something similar.
